# Take Python Function and Generate All Derivatives

Tags: python, lambda, python-2.7, scipy, sympy

I have a python function with variable number of arguments:

```
F(x1, x2, ... , xN)
```

I want to automatically generate N functions representing the derivatives of F with respect to each argument.

```
F'_1 = dF/dx1
F'_2 = dF/dx2
...
F'_N = dF/dxN
```

For example, I be able to give both 
F(x1) = sin(x1)
and
F(x1, x2) = sin(x1) * cos(x2)
and get all the derivatives automatically.

---

Edit2:
If function F was 2 variable (fixed number of arguments), I could use

```
   def f(x,y):
      return  sin(x)*cos(y)

   from sympy import *
   x, y = symbols('x y')
   f_1 = lambdify((x,y), f(x,y).diff(x))
```

Comment: To be clear- the function is something like `def F(x): return math.sin(x)`? (That is, it's not a symbolic representation of `sin(x)`, but an actual Python function?)

Comment: If it be possible that F(x) be non-symbolic, it's better. (i.e. using lambdify to get symbolic expression).

Comment: Do you already have a method for generating a numerical derivative on a function with one argument?

Comment: I need symbolic derivative function. i.e. for sin(x) I want to have cos(x) not numerical derivative in a point.

Comment: it would be good to show in the question a use of lambdify/SymPy to get a derivative on a single argument to the function. That would both catch us up on the methods to use and show research effort.

Comment: That answers a lot! Just one more question, then I'll know the solution: how would you do a partial derivative using SymPy if the function has two arguments?

Comment: Edited as you suggested!

Comment: Answer posted- it assumes you want the `lambidy` version of each function. If you take out the `lambdify` part, you'll see the result is `[cos(x)*cos(y), -sin(x)*sin(y)]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to use `inspect.getargspec` to get the names of all the arguments to the function. After that, it's a simple list comprehension:

```
import inspect
from sympy import *

def get_derivatives(func):
    arg_symbols = symbols(inspect.getargspec(func).args)
    sym_func = func(*arg_symbols)

    return [lambdify(arg_symbols, sym_func.diff(a)) for a in arg_symbols]
```

For example:

```
def f(x, y):
    return sin(x)*cos(y)

all_derivatives = get_derivatives(f)
```

Comment: If the OP could work with expressions instead of functions, things become much simpler: `{v: expr.diff(v) for v in expr.free_symbols}`.

Comment: Many Thanks! How I can call the generated derivative. i.e. F_1(0,0) or F_2(0,0)

Comment: `F1` is `all_derivatives[0]`, `F2` is `all_derivatives[1]`, so you could call it like `all_derivatives[0](0, 0)`.

Comment: @Hesam: OP == Original Poster == asker == you :)

Comment: If you insist on using functions, just pass it symbolic dummy arguments to get a symbolic object.

Comment: @asmeurer: That's exactly what my answer does (in the creation of `sym_func`). The only difference is using `for a in arg_symbols` instead of `for v in expr.free_symbols`, and the use of the lambdify to return (as requested) functions rather than expressions.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I don't like your solution, in that it uses strings instead of Symbols.  Quite a few things in SymPy automatically convert strings into Symbols, but not all. It would be better to use Symbol objects explicitly.

Comment: @asmeurer: What are you talking about? `arg_symbols` is an array of Symbol objects, not strings.

Comment: Might be better to do `symbols(inspect.getargspec(func).args, cls=Dummy)` to avoid any possible name clashes (true, it won't happen if you always name your symbols the same as the variables that hold them, but it's good practice to use Dummy to represent dummy variables).