# Generating function derivative as Python callable function

Tags: python, function, sympy, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I was reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178101/take-python-function-and-generate-all-derivatives) and I was trying to do the same, but I want the function to have a single parameter say `x`. And that parameter is an array of "values" to be filled by an optimization solver. For instance:

```
def f(x):
   return x[0]**2 + 3*x[1]
```

That function will refer to: `f(x)=x^2 + 3y`, meaning `x` is an array of variables. Those variables will be present on the current function or not, because they are all the variables in the whole optimization problem, meaning they can be present on the constraints. So I will like to find that functions partial derivatives of all variables. So,in this case, i will need 2 callable functions so I can use it to form a new array that is the Jacobian of the function. Is there a way to do that? How?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am the author of `pyneqsys`.

If you are open to using a library, [pyneqsys](https://github.com/bjodah/pyneqsys/) does exactly this. If not, you can look at the source of [pyneqsys/symbolic.py](https://github.com/bjodah/pyneqsys/blob/efcab5a/pyneqsys/symbolic.py#L149) which (approximately) does this to calculate the jacobian:

```
f = sympy.Matrix(self.nf, 1, self.exprs)
x = sympy.Matrix(self.nx, 1, self.x)
J = f.jacobian(x)
```

You then need to use `sympy.lambdify` to obtain a callable with the expected syntax of your particular solver.

Comment: I downloaded **pyneqsys** but haven´t been able to try it out due to lack of time, will do soon. I´ll let you know how it went